# how i can import firebase dynamicLinks Expo React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, firebase-dynamic-links

Hello how i can import this:
dynamicLinks().resolveLink(url).then((resolvedData) => {
… // Do what you need to do here
}
here don't explain how import this:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/deep-linking/#third-party-integrations